# NSTimer with Swift in SpriteKit able to build but crashes

Tags: swift, xcode6, nstimer

I am trying to create a new NSTimer object to simply increment my counter by 1sec (To calculate the lifetime of my game)  now I've seen demos and examples on how to go about this, and have done the same thing but the project continues to fail. Any suggestions to there?
This is the error message :
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a83c7d0

```
import SpriteKit


var timerObject = NSTimer()
var count = 0
let timer = SKLabelNode(text: "0")


class GameScene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    timerObject = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 1 , target: self  , selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    func result(){
         count++
         timer.text = String(count)

    }
```

I also wrote the function "result" as such and still crashed

```
func result() {
    count+= 0
    timer.text = "\(count)"
}
```

Comment: Pretty vague about the type and line location of failure.  Was the result() function called? Also, I would suggest you clean up your example and indent it better to make it easier to read for the people trying to help you.

Comment: well the crash says "Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT" And lands on                 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {... if that helps also i believe to display a timer on a SKLableNode you only strictly need the information I've provided above if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the answer for all those experiencing the same problem , it was I was experiencing the Error message: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a83c7d0 well the solution is quite simple actually , I had initialized my timerObject object inside viewDidLoad more specifically the error states that the method result is not a part of gameScene 
simply move the selector function of your choice underneath viewDidLoad and it should work just fine

```
class GameScene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


var timer = NSTimer()
var count = 0
let lableTimer = SKLabelNode(text: "0")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

     timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "result", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    lableTimer.position = timerPosition
    lableTimer.fontSize = 40


    self.addChild(lableTimer)

 }


func result(){
    count++
    lableTimer.text = String(count)
}
```

Also I've moved all my initial variables inside the GameScene class rather then on top.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NSTimer` callback has the wrong signature.  Try this:

```
func result(aTimer: NSTimer!) {
    count+= 0
    timer.text = "\(count)"
}
```

I believe you'll also need to pass the selector as "result:":

```
timerObject = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 1 , target: self  , selector: "result:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: I've replaced my code with yours and still seem to get the same problem unfortunately